# SSRS bar chart order by value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following data:

```
-----------------
Name|Value|Type
-----------------
A   | 110 | Daily
-----------------
A   | 770 | Weekly
-----------------
B   | 150 | Daily
-----------------
B   | 700 | Weekly
-----------------
C   | 120 | Daily
-----------------
C   | 840 | Weekly
```

In SSRS bar chart, the Name will be X axis, the Value will be Y axis, the Type will be series.

What I need is the bar chart will sort by the Weekly Value descending, so the expected order should be:

```
C Weekly
C Daily
A Weekly
A Daily
B Weekly
B Daily
```

How to do that? In query or in SSRS chart setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate sequential number for each `Name` based on the `Value` for `Weekly` type and which will then be the basis on how the records will be sorted.

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  Name, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
    WHERE   Type = 'Weekly'
)
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN records b
            ON a.Name = b.Name
ORDER   BY b.rn, a.Type DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/889f0/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ NAME ║ VALUE ║  TYPE  ║
╠══════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ C    ║   840 ║ Weekly ║
║ C    ║   120 ║ Daily  ║
║ A    ║   770 ║ Weekly ║
║ A    ║   110 ║ Daily  ║
║ B    ║   700 ║ Weekly ║
║ B    ║   150 ║ Daily  ║
╚══════╩═══════╩════════╝
```